# AngularFire 'firing' twice on console.log

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

```
mainApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$firebase', '$location', function ($scope, $firebase, $location) {
  var queueRef = new Firebase("https://myfirebase.firebaseio.com");
  var queueSync = $firebase(queueRef).$asArray();
  queueSync.$loaded(function () {
    console.log(queueSync.length);
    for (var x=0; x < queueSync.length; x++) {
        console.log(queueSync[x].caseNumber);
    }
  });
}]);
```

Using the above code, I get the console.log() statements to fire two times when I reload the page.  Is there a simple explanantion why they log twice?

Comment: can you give a plunker or fiddle

Comment: There could be many reasons, including that the data becomes available in batches. Given that **Firebase synchronizes data and changes to that data**, you should never depend on events firing only once (unless you call the `once` method in the Web/JavaScript API of course). If you want to know why it fires multiple times in your case, set a breakpoint and see what is different in the available data between the times that it hits.

Comment: What is the value of queueSync.length? What is the data? Please provide all the components we need to understand and reproduce the issue. See [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)